# Stacking combat triggers with Raffine, Scheming Seer

Tags: magic-the-gathering, mtg-stack

I have 3 opponents and attack one of them with [Raffine, Scheming Seer](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=558725) and a Grizzly Bears equipped with [Blade of Selves](https://gatherer.wizards.com/pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=446910).

If I stack the triggered abilities such that Blade of Selves' resolves before Raffine's does, do I have a creature connive for 2 or for 4?

Another way to phrase this question is, is X determined for this kind of triggered ability when the ability is triggered, or when it resolves? If it is determined at the time of triggering, I would have a creature Connive for 2, but if its determined on resolution, I would have a creature Connive for 4 (because I have 3 attacking Grizzly Bears instead of 1).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**You can have a creature connive for 4.**

Raffine's ability has this text:

> Whenever you attack, target attacking creature connives X, where X is the number of attacking creatures

This is handled by [rule 107.3c](https://mtg.fandom.com/wiki/Numbers_and_symbols), which says

> If a spell or activated ability has an {X}, [-X], or X in its cost and/or its text, and the value of X is defined by the text of that spell or ability, then that’s the value of X while that spell or ability is on the stack. The controller of that spell or ability doesn’t get to choose the value. **Note that the value of X may change while that spell or ability is on the stack.**

So, the value of X will update while the ability is on the stack, which means that if you stack it as specified, it will have the value 4 as the ability resolves.

Answer (score 2):

You will connive 3 assuming Raffine doesn't attack (3 Bears) or 4 if they do (3 bears and a Sphinx). Note that Raffine's ability does not require that they are attacking.

Also note, that you can only target Raffine (if they are attacking) or the attacking equipped Grizzly Bear with Raffine's ability as the two Grizzly Bear tokens from Blade of Selves will not exist at the time you need to pick a target for Raffine's triggered ability.

This could matter if your opponent wants to remove the Conniving creature to prevent the +1/+1 counters from discarding a nonland card to Connive.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).